# Having problems with running bundle install on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using thor 1.0.1
Using ffi 1.12.2 (x86-mingw32)
Fetching puma 3.12.4
Installing puma 3.12.4 with native extensions
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Fetching rubyzip 2.3.0
Installing rubyzip 2.3.0
Using tilt 2.0.10
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.2
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using i18n 1.8.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.7
Using nokogiri 1.10.9 (x86-mingw32)
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using mail 2.7.1
Using addressable 2.7.0
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/installation
data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
"D:/installation data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe" -r
./siteconf20200429-5116-m9ymp2.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: D:/installation
data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
make "DESTDIR=" clean
Makefile:264: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

current directory: D:/installation
data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1/ext/skiptrace
make "DESTDIR="
Makefile:264: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in D:/installation
data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bindex-0.8.1 for
inspection.
Results logged to D:/installation
data/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/bindex-0.8.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bindex (0.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bindex -v '0.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  web-console was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
    bindex
```

Comment: Have you tried to run "gem install bindex -v '0.8.1'"?

Comment: yeah tried that and problem  still persisted

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug in the version of Ruby you are using. Try upgrading your Ruby version to latest version of `2.3`.
My suggestion is not to use RailsInstaller at all. It's an outdated package that causes a lot of problems during development. If you want to install Ruby on Rails on Windows, RubyInstaller is the best option right now. It uses Windows Subsystem for Linux which provides a Linux environment on top of Windows.